# Method does not exist or incorrect signature: getInstance from the type

Tags: warning

I have a line of code who is accessing custom settings.

```
Foundation_Countries__c myCS2 = Foundation_Countries__c.getInstance('United States');
String myCCInst = myCS2.Country_code__c;
```

In Visual Studio Code I am getting a warning like this one:
Method does not exist or incorrect signature: getInstance from the type Foundation_Countries__c

The Apex class works and I don't get any error while running, but I wonder why I get this warning?

In IntelliJ, with the illuminated cloud extension, my colleague doesn't get the same warning.

Any idea on how can I be sure that those warnings will or will not impact my code?

Comment: You're most likely missing metadata files from your org. Try using Refresh Subject Definitions from the command palette, make sure your files in the repo are to to date, and that you're running an appropriate version of Java on your computer. Watch for any warnings or errors when you start VS Code

Comment: If you mean the refresh Sobject definitions, done! No errors regarding Java. Any warnings or errors when I start VS Code.